# Do we need a tag for classroom behavior/etiquette/discipline?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need a tag for classroom behavior/etiquette/discipline? When retagging [What to do about a professor who doesn't seem to grasp the concept of e-books?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/120246/what-to-do-about-a-professor-who-doesnt-seem-to-grasp-the-concept-of-e-books), I was unsure of what to use.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we need a “classroom” or “lecture-hall” tag? I think the issue here is the addition of venue-specific behavior more than just etiquette, is de we already have the latter tag.

Comment: We do already have [tag:coursework] although it doesn't seem to get used very often (maybe that tag implies that it's about actual assignments rather than course-based education more broadly). I feel like there should be a tag to differentiate the university-level course/classroom questions from questions about research relationships.